# Can I use a .htaccess file to secure folders on my computer (using MAMP) from others on my network?

Tags: macos, security, .htaccess, mamp

I have a simple question.

I'm using MAMP for development on my Mac. Once MAMP is on I access it using either localhost or 127.0.0.1. However, others can access it on my network using my IP address, I want to forbid this. Would anyone else even outside of my network have access when I'm connected to an internet connection?

I've put a .htaccess file in my MAMP home directory, which works as far as I've tested on other computers on the network. But how secure is this?

Thanks.

Here is what I am using:

> order deny,allow
>
> deny from all
>
> allow from 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your httpd.conf and remove/comment out any other `Listen` directives:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: Ok I will. What will this do? Thanks

Comment: I've added that, and removed 'Listen 80'

Comment: That should cover it! Now Apache is only listening for connections from `127.0.0.1` -- it can't receive connections from any other machine, even on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess is the best way to protect your online content, but if you really want to be sure, and you're behind a router, you could simply not forward port 80, so other people won't be able to access your server. Also disabling port 80 in your firewall would help I think.